# initialValues in redux form wizard do not work with FieldArray

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I hope I can explain my problem understandably. I wanted to use redux-form(wizard) for a shop cart.

At the beginning I dispatch the initialize action with the data for the cart, these looks like:
kitchens: `[{"id": "2-1-1-1-5-9-2", "deliveryOption": "selfservice"},{"id": "2-1-6-1-5-9-2","deliveryOption": "selfservice"}]`
In my Wizard I render the FieldArray with name "kitchens" but in this fields prop is always empty? I also tried to add an "Add-Button" where i use fields.push()?
Now an new Kitchen is added in values but also fields is empty.

Can somebody help me?

Here is a simply Overview of my code:
https://jsbin.com/pawezu/33/edit?js,output

Comment: please let me see your code

Comment: I've updated the question, thx for your help

Comment: where is the reducer?

Comment: reducer and initial action is also updated

Comment: i moved my code to a jsbin :)

Comment: please share the link

Comment: The Link is above

Answer (score 1):

I've found the Problem, my store tree key for the form reducer was "formReducer" but this will only work when the key is "form"

Answer (score 0):

In your components/wizard/Cart.jsx FieldArray should be: `<FieldArray name="kitchens" component={renderField} />`

Comment: I want that FieldArray renders my Kitchens View, the renderField is in Kitchens view

Comment: i think there is problem in your action

Comment: ok but when i click on the add member button it pushes in the values tree for kitchens a new entry?

Comment: when you are clicking on the button fields array is getting populated with initial values?

Comment: nope the fields array is then also empty but the values tree of the formReducer becomes a new value

Comment: where is reducer in jsbin?

Comment: I only use the redux-form reducer at the end near createStore

Comment: please post mapStateToProp() over here

Comment: I'm not using a container here this has to work also without

Comment: the values were dispatched with the initialize action from redux-form